# How to override element.style max-width in my CSS?

Tags: css

I am trying to override a element.style { max-width: 750px;} CSS style in my code and cannot figure out how to override it.

This is the line of code it is appearing in:

```
<ul class="rslides rslides1" id="slider3" style="max-width: 750px;">
```

Here is what is showing in my inspector panel at the top:

```
element.style {
    max-width: 750px;
}
```

I do not have max-width in my code and cannot get anything to override it.

Hopefully someone can help me out,
Thanks.

Comment: Inline styling (via the `style` attribute) is always [more specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) then CSS within the stylesheet. Though I highly suggest *not* doing this, you could use `!important` to overwrite it.. `max-width: 750px!important`... I'd avoid that though. I'd suggest reading up on [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Answer (score 1):

Use `!important` in your css, like:

```
ul#slider3{
    max-width: none !important;
}
```

It sounds like jQuery is adding the inline style after the document loads, since you say that it is not in your code.

The only time the inline style will take ultimate precedence over CSS `!important` styles is when the inline style also has `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

If you set max-width to 750 nothing will be bigger than 750 width. If you want to have something bigger than 750 sometimes then you can set it to width:750 without the max-

CSS max-width has a funtion, nothing can violate this width in any way specially if you ser html and body to max width to 750.

Now if you have a single div with this max-width but your html body donot have this set to 750 and you can overwrite it by adding a div inside using display:absolute

Answer (score 0):

jQuery responsive slides (rslides) has options you can customise. One of these options is the maxwidth.

e.g.

```
 $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
  maxwidth: "",           // Integer: Max-width of the slideshow, in pixels
 });
```

(Note: there are other other options as well)

have a look at the documentation here: http://responsiveslides.com

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the same problem today.. this seems to work well.

**First make it `none`**

Like this ,

```
max-width: none;
```

and then put your style

**Usage:**

Make it `none` as above, and then put your own style, for example,

```
style="max-width: none; width : 300px;"
```

This overrides it well.